# Get maximum bandwidth of a Network Adapter

Tags: networking, adapter

I would like to know how do I obtain the max bandwidth of my network adapter?

I can read it when I open my Network settings panel (eg, Wired Connected - 100Mb/s), but I would to obtain this value diagrammatically. Wireless is not needed.

Thanks in advance,

Pedro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ethtool.  ethtool can be used to query and change settings such as speed, auto- negotiation and checksum offload on many network devices, especially Ethernet devices.

To install ethtool in ubuntu, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install ethtool
```

If you want to find what type of network card is used, its speed, on which IRQ it is listed, and the chip type used, you use the following command :

```
dmesg |grep eth0
```

But keep this in mind:

- Cat 6 cable should squeeze more speed out of your connection
- Cable length - Keep it as short as possible
- Your best speed results will be between 2 computers. Internet usage
  speeds will be lower in most cases.
- Make sure jumbo frames are set in network properties for your network
  adapter.
- Hard Disk speed can bottleneck your transfers

Answer (score 4):

You can either use mii-tool (which I've myself had success with in the past). You can also try ethtool, as [mentioned here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-linux-lan-card-find-out-full-duplex-half-speed-or-mode/).

Both will need to be run as root.